# Bootstrap 3. How to make the block's header not have paddings inherited from container, but still controlled by columns

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

maybe the title is not clear, so I will try to provide explanation as clear as possible.

I have the

```
.container{
   max-width: 1200px;
   padding-left: 50px;
   padding-right: 50px;
}
```

Because we do not want the Bootstrap to stretch beyond 1200px.

I also got 2 blue-highlighted headers for the contents, that should not be affected by the container's paddings, i.e. have full-width of the column without 50px of whitespace from left and right.

And I also got 2 spaces for contents.

Here's the First **[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/mAyVKhFvMV)** example to demonstrate.

As of the current markup, it is fine before the content starts to collapse and the rules from `.col-xs-12` begin to apply and the panels begin to have 100% width.

This results, as you can see, in Header 2 not being directly above the Content 2.
And this is expectable because I got the markup that aligning the items absolutely in a way it should. In particular, I simply got 4 columns, and it is clear why the **Header 2** collapses right after **Header 1** because markup controls it.

Here's second example of markup at **[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/QPggqP2Ox6)**

I got a different markup here. I got only **2 columns** now and this results in them collapsing correctly and logically, not like in the **First example.**

In this particular case, everything is fine on all viewport sizes below 1200px. When you increase it to, for example, 1400px you will see that it behaves in a different way from the first example.

In particular, if you inspect elements of both examples when you are on the 1400px viewport size, you will see that the **First example** has `margin-left & right: auto` affected by `container` and it results in the `max-width: 1200px` applied to it correctly and as the viewport increases, the space from left and right increase.

Whilst in the **Second example** it does not and the space from left and right remain the same.

Any idea how to refactor the code so as I got the behavior of **Second example** below 1200px combined with the behavior of **First example** after 1200px ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure this is the behaviour you want. Interestingly, no custom CSS needed. But lots of nested cols, rows, etc.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"><!-- this splits the whole thing in 2 on md+ -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 blue"><!-- this is needed to have the header background continue to the edge -->
          <div class="row"><!-- all these rows are important to remove double margins you get when nested cols within cols. Rows have negative 15px margin -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-4 blue">Heading 1</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-4 red">Content 1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 green">Heading 2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 orange">Content 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/x6vMzkqCMK